# obtaining an execution plan on stored procedure sqlplus

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sqlplus

So i am fairly new to using sqlplus and looking through execution plans.
What i normally do is the following below:

```
set timing on;
set autotrace on;
"sql statement goes here"
```

I understand that this is typically done for simple/solo sql statements and you can't do the same for a stored procedure.

But i was wondering if i was to take all the sql statements out of the stored procedure and place them into a script and run each one after the other. Or just run the entire procedure. Is there a way i can log each of execution plans into a txt file so i have them to view.

Or is there a way to look at the execution plan for a stored procedure?

any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: You will have to do it manually one/one statement using `EXPLAIN PLAN` but can't be done for entire SP.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but I think you can. [DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY_CURSOR](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_xplan.htm#i998364) works off a sql_id. You would have to look up the sql_id's for the DML statements in your procedure, which may be a bit of a pain, but I think they should stay in the cache long enough.

If you're trying to profile the performance of a PL/SQL block, you may also want to look at [DBMS_PROFILER](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_profil.htm).